# Building Maven module for different product lines

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

In a J2EE project, I have some Maven submodules that need to be built for different product lines. In most cases, the different versions for the product lines only differ in having some differences in the configuration files contained in *META-INF*. The code stays the same, though.

Is it possible to keep these configuration differences within a single module and build differently configured versions from it in one build pass? If not, what is the recommended way to build different versions of the same module without duplicating cide?

Comment: `Building For Different Environments with Maven` https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Comment: Hm, is it possible to build the artifacts for all product lines in a single build pass somehow?

Comment: Could be done via: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/

Comment: @khmarbaise, does this also work for multi module projects?